# matchers and matcher should be synonyms

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

I think they mean the same thing and we should prefer the singular form matcher.

Also there are some not so good usages of the tags, where they probably should be replaced by pattern-matcher or something. (sorry for the off-topic stuff on the question, but otherwise it gets rejected as low quality ..)

Answer (score 1):

The tag [matchers](/questions/tagged/matchers) has 15 questions and the tag [matcher](/questions/tagged/matcher) 145 so a little "hand job" should at least remove the plural form.

But I seriuously doubt this tag. I think they can be removed with some specific tags like [pattern-matcher](/questions/tagged/pattern-matcher).

Comment: I think matcher is a valid tag for matcher libraries. See my tag-wiki proposal.

Comment: @JensSchauder, possibly, they could cause problems with pattern matching so a matcher-library tag is maybe wise.